# hpp/cpp split with global function: Multiple definition of ... error

Tags: c++, c++11, linker, prototype, header-files

**EDIT: The problem is the forgotten include guard. Sorry!**

So I'm trying to consequently apply two file rule where all declarations go into a ***.hpp*** file and all definitions into the corresponding **.cpp** file. My problem are global functions in libraries whose header gets included in multiple locations.
 
**For example:**

```
/* lib1.hpp */
namespace lib1{
int addNumbers(int a, int b);
}
```

and the cpp file:

```
/* lib1.cpp */
namespace lib1{
int addNumbers(int a, int b) {return a + b;}
}
```

Now if I include **lib1.hpp** in multiple libraries, say **lib2**, **lib3** and then include both, **lib2** and **lib3** in any other library or executable-file,

> I get the *multiple definitions of addNumbers()* error.

This makes sense to me, but I can't figure out how to solve this issue. I tried the `extern` keyword, but it doesn't change anything:

```
/* lib1.hpp */
namespace lib1{
extern int addNumbers(int a, int b);
}
```

and the cpp file remains the same:

```
/* lib1.cpp */
#include "lib1.hpp"

namespace lib1{
int addNumbers(int a, int b) {return a + b;}
}
```

It would work if I created a surrounding class for the functions in **lib1.hpp**, but that doesn't help me understand the problem and adds a redundant namespace like `lib1::lib1::addNumbers()` for instance.

Comment: try to change `namespace lib1{ int addNumbers(int a, int b) {return a + b;} }` to `int lib1::addNumbers(int a, int b) {return a + b;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a `#define` in your **.hpp** file as shown below

```
/* lib1.hpp */
#ifndef __LIB_1__
#define __LIB_1__
namespace lib1{
int addNumbers(int a, int b);
}
#endif /*__LIB_1__*/
```

Comment: As usual, I was looking far far deeper for a problem. Seems I forgot the include guards for once :/

Comment: @potAito ha ha all techies will do some small mistakes likes this :)

Answer (score 1):

1.) Add inline keyword if your function should be defined in a header file.

2.) I think names that start with two underscores are reserved for the compiler.

Comment: No, don't add inline keyword, that would make no sense.

Comment: inline keyword would make sense if I defined and delcared the functions in the hpp file.

Answer (score 1):

As "Let Us Embed" has told use preprocessor directives to avoide repetitive declarations.

```
# pragma once ///if the compiler supports
```

for other compilers use:

```
#ifndef EXAMPLE
#define EXAMPLE
Add your code
#endif
```

Comment: Most compilers support the pragma nowadays. It does not depend on the Idea.

Comment: yes you are correct ...  it is compiler dependent issue